# Unusual Error on Exchange Server 2019 Enterprise

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange, windows-server-2019, microsoft-office

I've got my own personal Microsoft Exchange Server 2019 Enterprise at home and I recently upgraded all the VMware Guests to Server 2022,  Rebuild all my domain controllers from scratch from 2012 R2 and 2016 Core only to all 2022 except my Exchange server is on 2019

The operation couldn't be performed because object 'activeDarkSiteFalse' couldn't be found on 'MY SERVER XXXXXXXX001'.  Everything is up to date, including hardware firmware, VMTools, Windows features and security updates, and I'm using CU12 Exchange 2019.  Also, Exchange 2019 Enterprise is licensed, which wasn't cheap for private fun.

Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 0):

How about the original environment? Did you mean you install Exchange 2019 CU12 on Windows 2012 R2/2016?
Based on the official document, both are not supported:

[Exchange Server supportability matrix | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019)
[image]

Since it is the test environment, you can delete all Exchange servers from ADSI and install Exchange 2019 CU12 directly after you upgrade the OS to Windows Server 2022.

You could refer to Exchange Deployment Assistant
https://assistants.microsoft.com/

Comment: Sorry,  my question was poorly worded.  My exchange server has always run Server 2019 it was built from a fresh Server 2019 ISO from VLSC.

I had 2 domain controllers
1x 2012 R2 (Running since 2014 to 2022)
1x 2019 Core (Running since early 2019 before 2019 was RTM to 2023)
Both of those were demoted and 2 new domain controllers were built not in that order :) 
Now my environment has 
1x 2022 DC, FSMO, GC
1x 2022 Secondary DC, GC
1x 2022 File server (Previously 2012R2 in-place upgrade)
1x 2022 CCTV Server (Previously 2016 in-place upgrade)
1x 2019 Exchange server

Comment: Did you mean that you got the error message after you upgrade DC?
How did you get this error? You could run Get-ADServerSettings | fl to check if Exchange connect to the new DC. If not, you could use Set-ADServerSettings to change it.